# Passing functions/state variables to a React Component (Arrow notation)

Tags: reactjs, react-props, arrow-functions

I have a React component that is declared in the arrow-function notation. This component has a child component that is supposed to change the state of the ParentComponent. How can I achieve that? And how would it look like if we passed the change of the state as a function (changeState in this case)?

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
    const changeState = () => setMyState(!myState);

    return(
        <ChildComponent /> // pass the state variables
    );
}

const ChildComponent = () => { // receive the state variables
    // change state of parent component
}
```

Comment: Pass props to `ChildComponent`? Why does the specific function notation matter?

Comment: I don't know how it would look like to execute a function call of a props in the child component

Comment: A lot of people ask this question about "changing the parent component from a child"... The truth is that you should not do that.  The "react" way of doing this is to "share" some kind of state using  a "store" like react-redux.  Otherwise you will find out soon or later that you shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Just add props parameter to your childcomponent and call it as props.func()

Comment: How do you normally execute a function call? It looks just the same. See e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass state changes to the child class you can just pass the functions as attributes to the child. This works for any function and you can even just pass in `setMyState` if you would like into the child function

```
 const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
    const changeState = () => setMyState(!myState);

    return(
        <ChildComponent 
            changeState={changeState}
        /> // pass the state variables
    );
}

const ChildComponent = ({changeState}) => { // receive the state variables
    // change state of parent component

    // you can use changeState here and 
    // it will update the parent component and rerender the page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass functions as a prop as well to child components.
Try passing the changeState function to the child component like this

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
    const changeState = () => setMyState(!myState);

    return(
        <ChildComponent handleChange={changeState} /> // pass the state variables
    );
}

const ChildComponent = ({handleChange}) => { // receive the state variables
    // change state of parent component by simply calling 
    // handleChange as a normal function 

}
```